# Convert SQL date to dd-mmmm-yyyy C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, date

I have a `date` field in an SQL table, if I try to save, either 09-02-2019 or 09-february-2019 he saves it to me, but the attempt to recover that date shows something like this (all together or with T ):

```
2019-02-09 00:00:00:000
```

I am trying to recover those values with EF and LINQ to be able to format the date, I try to implement this:

**DATE PROPERTIES IN MY CLASS ORDERS**

```
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime? fechaInicio { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime? fechaExpo { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime? fechaEntrega { get; set; }
```

**GET DATA LIST**

```
//TRAER LISTA DE ORDENES
  public List<mapOrdenesListaTemp> listadoOrdenes()
  {
     var lista = new List<mapOrdenesListaTemp>();

      using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
      {
         lista = ctx.Ordenes.Select(m => new mapOrdenesListaTemp
                                    {
fechaInicio=Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaInicio).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
fechaExportacion= Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaExpo).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
fechaEntrega= Convert.ToDateTime(m.fechaEntrega).ToString("dd-mmmm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

                                     }).ToList();  

      }
```

**I TRY TO ASSIGN THE DATA HERE (CLASS mapOrdenesListaTemp)**

```
public class mapOrdenesListaTemp
{
    public string fechaInicio { get; set; }
    public string fechaEntrega { get; set; }
    public string fechaExportacion { get; set; }
}
```

But I get this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String ToString(System.String, System.IFormatProvider)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I know I can't use `.ToString ()` as the error is telling me, but how do I recover the data and then apply the conversion (I would like to pass the date from `2019-02-09` to `09-February-2019`? Anyway to get around this error, I do not know if my code is correct?)

Comment: If I may, I think you don't fully understand the difference between the date value and the date _representation_. The value is a large int, basically the number of units of time since a default date (like 1 january 1900 or 1-1-1970, the Unix epoch). When you read data from a database, you get a date value. And the value you are getting is perfectly fine. You just need to _format_ it as you need when you output it. Like `fechaInicio?.ToString("dd mmmm yyyy")`. You can also specify culture, with toString overloads. Am I missing something?

Comment: @A.Chiesa correct, I need to format the output to `ToString("dd mmmm yyyy")` , I find that way to convert the date on internet but I don't know if is the correct way to do this

Comment: Yes it is ;) Basically you keep the date in it's "value form" (no official term: it's just a DateTime value) all through your app. Except when you output the value: the user is going to see a string, anyway, so you can choose how to perform the formatting. If you don't, the framework is going to pick the default format string. And that is what you are seeing.

Comment: I really think @A.Chiesa nailed it -- a date is its own datatype.  How you render it is another matter.  How is this being displayed?  In a form, in a web app, on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is quite clear. You cannot format date in EF query because it cannot be translated to equivalent sql.

Alternatively you can do as follows:

```
lista = ctx.Ordenes.Select(m => new { m.fechaInicio, m.fechaExpo, m.fechaEntrega}).ToList();

var listWithFormattedDate = lista.Select(m => new mapOrdenesListaTemp
                            {
                               fechaInicio = m.fechaInicio?.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                               fechaExportacion= m.fechaExpo?.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                               fechaEntrega= m.fechaEntrega?.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use 
1. DateTime datatype, then the value would be stored as below example
1998-01-02 10:10:50.600
2. Date datatype, then the value would be stored as below example
1998-01-02 **00:00:00.000** - Time field will be always there but would be 00:00:00.000

My suggestion in this case would be is to convert the date datatype to string while saving and retrieving the value to and from DB